# Is this version of openssl vulnerable?

Tags: openssl, debian

I have an old Debian 3.1 (kernel 2.4.19) where the version of ssl is

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8c 05 Sep 2006
```

I read that there was some issue about random generator being guessable.

https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571

But then it seems that the version I use is not vulnerable because it is just before the change. Or is there a way to verify this? Should I try and upgrade OpenSSL regardless of it being vulnerable or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Probably vulnerable.

CVEDetails has a [list of 49 vulnerabilities for that version.](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=217&product_id=383&version_id=37271)

Take your pick.

Also: Debian 3.1 has had [no security updates for nine years](https://www.debian.org/releases/sarge/).